# Adwords API PHP example to fetch search volume for related keywords

Tags: php, google-ads-api

I understand that the [TargetingIdeaService](http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/docs/reference/v201003/TargetingIdeaService.html) is the service to be used to fetch monthly search volume for multiple keywords related to a given keyword.

Is there a PHP example somewhere showing how to do that? (by which I mean a small application that lets user enter a keyword, and feedback related keywords with monthly search volumes).

I am struggling to get the related keywords strings back from the results: $data['KEYWORD']->value; does not return the actual keyword string, and I cannot find how to access the keyword string.

Answer (score 0):

Searching on github is good place to finding answer on your question. For example this repo can help you: https://github.com/medio/Google-Adwords-API-PHP/blob/master/examples/v201209/Optimization/GetKeywordIdeas.php